# In Flutter, how to display image from specific "texture coordinate" and crop the rest?

Tags: image, flutter, crop

For example, I have an image of 1200 x 800.

I want to display the image from point (125, 47) to point (746, 693).

Anything on point less than x = 125, y = 47, and more than x = 746, y = 693, should be cropped out (or not displayed on widget).

This shouldn't matter about the widget dimension.

How can I achieve this in Flutter? All I can see is plugins to bring UI dialog to let the user crop the image, which is *not* what I needed. Even if there's a solution to process the image on the local cache first before being displayed is ok.

Comment: use a `CustomPaint` where you can draw any part of your image with `Canvas.drawImageRect` method - the docs say: *"Draws the subset of the given image described by the src argument into the canvas in the axis-aligned rectangle given by the dst argument."*

Comment: @pskink ah ok, let me look up the `CustomPaint`.